# Getting a private access error in a subclass

Tags: java, subclass

I am trying to override the withdraw method so that in the savings account it cannot be overdrawn. When I compile this I get an error telling me that balance has private access in the class BankAccount. I am also required to leave the double balance as private.

```
import java.util.*;
public class BankAccount {
    private int id;
    private double balance,
    public BankAccount(int id,double balance) {
        this.id = id;
        this.balance = balance;
    }    
    public void setBalance (double balance){
        this.balance = balance;
    }
    public double getBalance (){
        return balance;
    }
    public void withdraw(double amount) {
        balance = balance - amount;
    }

}

public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount {
    
    public SavingsAccount(int id, double balance) {
        super(id,balance);
    }
    public void withdraw(double amount) {
          if(balance >= amount) {
              super.withdraw(amount);
            }
    }
        
        
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use the getter methods you declared? eG. change `if(balance >= amount)` to `if(getBalance() >= amount)`

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it. Should've seen that

Answer (score 0):

You have a public getter for *balance*, you should use that.

Since your member variable is private, compiler is going to complain surely. And that is what it is going.